# Finding remainders of very large numbers

Tags: modulo

I understand I can use // to divide very large numbers (limited by machine memory) and get the integer value back without overflow error. However, I'm trying to test whether the very large integer number is divisible without remainder by another number. (This is of course equivalent to modulo of the divisor, mathematically.) But how do I test the very large number is evenly divided by the smaller one? Which is equivalent to whether there is a decimal portion returned when the division is performed. The // only gives me the integer portion of the result, leaving me in the dark about whether there would have been a decimal portion in the true mathematical result?true

Comment: I meant to say that this is a Python question

Comment: What have you tried so far? can you please share some code?

Answer (score 0):

% Modulus   Divides left hand operand by right hand operand and returns remainder

Using this, you can write code that checks whether it returns a zero or not to determine if your numbers divide evenly or if there will be a remainder.

Comment: Do you know if % Modulus is reliable for integers with 308+ digits?